# Does the casting of a Shield Guardian's stored spell take up an action?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, monsters, actions

I have seen this question: "[How does the amulet wearer control a Shield Guardian, and when does it act?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79797/how-does-the-amulet-wearer-control-a-shield-guardian-and-when-does-it-act)" But it seems to fail to address the question of if casting a stored spell takes up an action,  and if so, whose action: the amulet wearer's or the guardian's?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While it's not specified, the action required to cast the stored spell should be the same as the action used to cast the spell normally, and must be taken by the shield guardian.

> When
>   commanded
>   to
>   do
>   so
>   by
>   the
>   wearer
>   or
>   when
>   a
>   situation
>   arises
>   that
>   was
>   predefined
>   by
>   the
>   spellcaster,
>   **the
>   guardian
>   casts
>   the
>   stored
>   spell**
>   with
>   any
>   parameters
>   set
>   by
>   the
>   original
>   caster,
>   requiring
>   no
>   components.

So the shield guardian is not just, for example, releasing the stored spell - they are *casting* it.

> Most
>   spells
>   require
>   a
>   single
>   action
>   to
>   cast,
>   but
>   some
>   spells
>   require
>   a
>   bonus
>   action,
>   a
>   reaction,
>   or
>   much
>   more
>   time
>   to
>   cast.

Not to sound obvious, but the casting time of a spell defines the time required to cast the spell. Since the guardian is casting the spell, they have to spend the appropriate amount of time.